# Lead form works on Mac Chrome and Brave but does not work on Mac Safari or IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I am getting a 409 conflict status for contact.php on Mac Safari when I hit the submit button. It does not respond on Iphone either. I do not understand why it works in some browsers but not others.

Here is the HTML and PHP. I am also not getting anything in the error logs. I imagine it is something simple I am overlooking.

````
                    <div class="heading-title  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <form class="getin_form wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="400ms" onsubmit="return false" method="post";">
                            <div class="row px-2">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="result1"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name1" class="d-none"></label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="name1" type="text" placeholder="Name:" required  name="userName">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email1" class="d-none"></label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email1" placeholder="Email:" name="email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="message1" class="d-none"></label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message1" placeholder="Message:" required  name="message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit_btn1" class="button gradient-btn w-100">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form> ```



``` <?php


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if($_POST)
{

    require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    $your_email = "contact@thordigi.com";  //Replace with recipient email address

    $to_Email       = $your_email;

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone =  $_POST["userPhone"];
    //$user_Subject =  $_POST["userSubject"];
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }


       //Server settings
//    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
//    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.googlemail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
//    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
//    $mail->Username   = 'website@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
//    $mail->Password   = 'your password';                         // SMTP password
//    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
//    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
     $mail->setFrom($user_Email,$user_Name);
     $mail->addAddress($your_email, 'Thordigi');     // Add a recipient
     $mail->addReplyTo($your_email, 'Information');


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'New Contact Inquiry from your Website';
    $mail->Body  = "<h4 style='text-align: center;padding: 25px 15px;background-color: #0c6c9e;color: #FFFFFF;font-size:16px;width:90%;border-radius: 10px;'>Hi There! You have a new inquiry from your website.</h4><br><br>";


    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .' Thank you for contacting us.'));
        die($output);
    }

}
header("Location: index.html")
?>```

```javascript
$("#submit_btn1 , #submit_btn").on('click', function () {
        let userName = $('#name1').val();
        let userEmail = $('#email1').val();
        let userMessage = $('#message1').val();
        let result;
        if(this.id === 'submit_btn'){
            result = $('#result');
            userMessage = $('#companyName').val();
            userName = $('#userName').val();
            userEmail = $('#email').val();
        }
        else{
            result = $('#result1');
        }
        //simple validation at client's end
        let postData, output;
        let proceed = true;
        if (userName === "") {
            proceed = false;
        }
        if (userEmail === "") {
            proceed = false;
        }
        if (userMessage === "") {
            proceed = false;
        }
        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if (proceed) {

            //data to be sent to server
            postData = {
                'userName': userName,
                'userEmail': userEmail,
                'userMessage': userMessage
            };

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact.php', postData, function (response) {
                //load json data from server and output message
                if (response.type === 'error') {
                    output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
                } else {
                    output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('.getin_form input').val('');
                    $('.getin_form textarea').val('');

                }

                result.slideUp("fast").html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');

        } else {
            output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">Please provide the missing fields.</div>';
            result.slideUp("fast").html(output).slideDown();
        }

    });```
````

Comment: You tagged this `javascript`, but I don't see much of it. But there must be some, I suppose, because you got `onsubmit="return false"` on your form - so without additional JavaScript, this would not submit anything to begin with.

Comment: Hey CBroe, my bad for forgetting that and thanks for pointing it out. I added it now.

Comment: I don't see you prevent the submit button click default action anywhere?